# What's the fundamental group of N in this example?

Tags: algebraic-topology

[enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827411/fundamental-group-of-torus-by-van-kampens-theorem/827503#827503)

In this page, in the first answer with pictures, it offered a computation of the fundamental group of torus by polygon, but what's the fundamental group of N?

Comment: $\mathbb N$,in the order topology is totoaly disconnected so it's fundamental group is trivial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ be the punctured torus depicted in the link and $V$ be a ball centered at the point removed. Including a loop from $U\cap V$ into $U$ gives a loop homotopic to the boundary loop $A^{-1}B^{-1}AB$. When included into $V$ we get the trivial loop. So $N=<<A^{-1}B^{-1}AB>>$ (normally generated group). This tells you that:

$$\pi_{1}(T^{2})=\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/<<A^{-1}B^{-1}AB>>=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Thanks,but I have a question, in the Hatcher's textbook:"the kernel of Φ is the normal subgroup N generated by all elements of the form iαβ(ω)iβα(ω)^−1 for ω ∈ π1(Aα ∩ Aβ)" But AB can not fromiαβ(ω) or iβα(ω),as π1(Aα ∩ Aβ)is Z, can not include two generators. Can you help me, thanks!

Comment: I would like to help but I'm afraid I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that as in the words from Hatcher's book N is generated by iαβ(ω)iβα(ω)^−1 for ω ∈ π1(Aα ∩ Aβ), in this sense, A−1B−1AB can be seen in the formiαβ(ω)iβα(ω)^−1. Then AB should be from iαβ(ω) or iβα(ω). But it seems impossible.

Comment: Remember that we are quotienting by $N$ to get $\pi_{1}(T^{2})$ from a free product. So we expect that the loops in $N$ are the ones that should be trivial viewed in $T^{2}$. $AB$ should not be trivial in this space so we should not expect it to appear in $N$.

Comment: I know that, but as A−1B−1AB is also in the form: αβ(ω)iβα(ω)^−1.SO in A−1B−1AB which is αβ(ω)and which is βα(ω)^−1? And could you tell me how you get that N is <<A−1B−1AB>>. Thanks.

Comment: If $U_{\alpha}=V$ and $U_{\beta}=U$ where $U,V$ are as above then $i_{\alpha\beta}(\omega)=A^{-1}B^{-1}AB$ (as explained in my answer since if we include a loop in the intersection into $U$ we get a loop homotopic to $A^{-1}B^{-1}AB$) and $i_{\beta\alpha}=e$ (trivial loop). Notice that $N=<<i_{\alpha\beta}(\omega)(i_{\beta\alpha}(\omega))^{-1}>>=<<A^{-1}B^{-1}AB>>$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16326/discussion-between-facebook-100006493752734-and-user71352).